# postive number ,negative number,two number after decimal ,

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[\d+\-\.]')),
```

Above code allow decimal negative value positive value

but it did not allow two numbers after decimal value and (-1.33455-122334-123) will appear
i only need (-1.222) not many negative value

Answer (score 0):

try this way...

```
double value = 1.23456789;
print('value: ${value.toStringAsFixed(2)}'); // output: 1.23
```

if get only positive value then...

```
if (value.isNegative == false) {
      print('value: ${value.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
  }
```

Comment: problem is i want it in text input and negitve,postive values

Comment: child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('value: ${value.toStringAsFixed(2)}'),
      ...

Comment: is it accept negative value also

Comment: if you want only positive value then check value like ...  value.isNegative

Comment: i want positive and negative value.       two number after decimal.        and only one (-) negative symbol appear in the text input